# If $C$ is a $m \times n$ matrix such that $Cx=b$ is consistent for all $b \in \mathbb{R^m}$, which of the statements is/are definitely correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

(I) For each $b \in \mathbb{R^m}$, there is a unique solution $x$.

(II) The column space of $C$ has dimension $m$.

(III) It is possible that $Cx=0$ has non trivial solutions.

I have put (II) as my answer to be the only statement that is correct. However I'm unsure if (III) can also be correct or not, need some help here thanks.

Comment: The phrasing "it is possible that $Cx=0$ has nontrivial solutions" is strange. Either $Cx=0$ has nontrivial solutions or it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align}
C =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
then clearly 
\begin{align}
Cx = b
\end{align}
has solutions for any $b \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Moreover, $(0, 0, 1)^T$ belongs in the kernel of $C$.